# MVC core API Azure WebApp Json

Tags: api, azure, web-applications, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC Core API and a MVC Core website running in Azure. The website accesses the API to retrieve pictures, which are roughly 2 ~ 3 MB in size. The pictures are transferred in JSON format together with a bunch of other information.

The problem is the transfer between the API and the website is horrendously slow. It can currently take up to over 6 seconds!

I eventually ruled out the blob storage and identified the bottleneck.

In the website, I call the API method using `HttpClient.GetAsync` and then deserialize the JSON contents from the response. This is the part which is very slow.

Is there any way of speeding up this procedure? Is there some Azure web app configuration I can set?

Many thanks

Comment: I can imagine deserializing 2 ~ 3 MB of Json (client side) can be slow... Why would you want to transfer the images as Json? Please look in to having the images returned as a file/stream. If you need the meta data, look into getting a file _name_ with its meta data, and getting the image as a file/stream.

Comment: I second Rick's comment: serializing/deserializing a 2-3MB file to json would be a bit expensive. Are the pictures public anyways? Maybe your API can simply return the link to the images and let the clients download from there?

Comment: The pictures are not public so I can't use a link. Just added some more logging and it turns out the biggest latency is from the HttpClient.GetAsync call. The client side json deserialization is very quick and only takes a fraction of a second. Calls between azure apps in the same region shouldn't be this slow. I think I'm missing something fundamental here

Comment: What size is you Azure instance? Depending on the size you can actually have bandwidth limitations. Have you also checked to make sure the slowdown is on the client server and not the API back-end itself taking some time to grab the file from storage? Outside of that, I'm not sure what to look at :/

Comment: Finally been able to come back to this project and it looks like the problem has gone away. Maybe there were some issues with Azure at the time but it's all performing well now. Thanks to everyone for their input.